# Error: could not find function "overlay" after reinstall

Tags: r, dictionary, r-sp

I reinstalled my pc and also reinstalled R, but I somehow get an error when running my R program:

> Error: could not find function "overlay"

which was fine on the previous installation.

The new R version is 3.2.4., so I tried to downgrade the version to 3.1.* and 3.0.*, but this was not helpful.

Libraries I used are:

```
library(sp)
library(maptools)
library(gstat)
library(rgdal)
library(sm)
library(png)
```

It seems like `overlay` is [included in the **sp** package](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/sp/docs/overlay). I don't know what to do.

Comment: Your packages got updated in the process and package sp has removed the `overlay` function. Update your code to reflect that change (I assume there is a now preferred alternative).

Comment: Thanks @Roland, for short term fix I  need to downgrade the sp package version, do you know where to get older version of sp package ??

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/index.html

Answer (score 3):

`overlay` is deprecated, see http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/sp/docs/overlay (and section 'Note' therein). It has been replaced with `over` that seemingly overcomes a set of inconsistencies associated with `overlay`. Edzer wrote a nice vignette about [Map overlay and spatial aggregation in `sp`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/vignettes/over.pdf) using the `over` function - you should probably have a look at it.